# Can quartz be sealed? If so, would it have beneficial effects?

Tags: kitchen-counters, stone, countertops, quartz

Quartz is not supposed to scratch and is not supposed to stain. Furthermore its not supposed to require sealing (unlike natural stone like granite).

I have what appears to be low quality quartz installed. It both scratches (for example from cast iron pans if dragged over the surface, or even from some dirty cardboard moving boxes that were moved while on the surface) and it stains (rust, coffee, wine, etc). The stains can sometimes be worked out with lots of elbow grease a concoction of cleaners, but sometimes remain deeply embeded. The scratches remain no matter what. The stone is white with grey areas/spots/design and the scratches are the same grey.

Would sealing the quartz help? Could it be harmful?

Incase it matters for any reason the quartz is from the MSI Q series.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest finding the local stone supplier (possibly through your local kitchen installer), and ask them.

It sounds like your quartz is more porous than usual is you are getting stains on it - unless you leave wine on it for hours you should normally have time to wipe it up.

Normally quartz benchtops aren't very porous, and so don't take up spilled liquids. This also means they don't take up sealant very well. Maybe your bench will take a sealant since it is more absorbent, but you'd be better talking to someone who can inspect your bench first, or even knows the quarry your stone came from.

I wouldn't expect sealing the bench to be harmful, if using usual stone sealing products.